# Date difference in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Let's say I have two dates in my table, DueDate and PaidDate.  What I need to do is calculate the difference between those two dates.  However, if the DateDiff() returns less than 0, it should show 0.

DateDiff(Day, 0, (PaidDate-DueDate-1)) as DelayDays

Should show 0 for anything less than 1.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, that's not how you use DateDiff. This is how you use it:

```
DateDiff(Day, PaidDate, DueDate)
```

To get a zero value, just compare the dates:

```
case when PaidDate > DueDate then 0 else DateDiff(Day, PaidDate, DueDate) end
```

(I'm not sure however which date you want to normally be the later one, i.e. if you want to calculate the time left or the time over due, so you might need to swap them around. As it stands now it calculates the time left.)

Comment: I read somewhere that doing DateDiff(Day, 0, PaidDate-DueDate) gives a better accuracy.  And the -1 in DueDate is just because I need not calculate for the day of the payment, ie calculating up until the day before day of payment.  Once again thank you.

Comment: @Rabin: If you (mis)use DateDiff that way it only gives better accuracy if you have a time component also that you want to take into account, i.e. the difference between '2010-06-27 23:00' and '2010-06-28 01:00' would be zero as it's less than 24 hours, while DateDiff would give the result one as it's different dates. So, it's only more accurate if that is actually the result that you want. However, if you want higher resolution, just use a smaller unit than `day` instead of using DateDiff merely as a way to round a number.

Comment: Oh, so if I do not plan to use the time component, it's better not to do DateDiff(Day, 0, DueDate-PaidDate) but rather DateDiff(Day, PaidDate, DueDate)?

Answer (score 1):

```
case when DateDiff(Day, 0, (PaidDate-DueDate-1)) <0 then 0 else
DateDiff(Day, 0, (PaidDate-DueDate-1))  end
```

Comment: Since this does the same calculation twice, I think Guffa's solution suits me little better.  Thanks for you help.